# How to give authority of PDA to another program

Tags: anchor, pda, authority

I have two programs.

// program one

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyContext<'info> {
   ...
   #[account(mut)]
   pub pda_in_prog_1: PDA_ONE<'info, T>,
   pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
```

// program two

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyContext<'info> {
   ...
   #[account(mut)]
   pub pda_in_prog_2: PDA_TWO<'info, T>,
   pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
```

Is there a way I can give program two authority over `pda_in_prog_1`. Some operations I want to carry out in program two might be closing or transferring funds from `pda_in_prog_1`.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure you can transfer a PDA authority to another program.
Although, instead of trying to update the PDA 1 in your program 2, you can build an instruction in program 1, that you call with a CPI. This way program 1 will have the necessary rights to update PDA 1

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can! The associated-token-account program is a great and simple example showing this.

A person's associated-token-account is a PDA on the associated-token-account program:

```
    Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[
            &wallet_address.to_bytes(),
            &token_program_id.to_bytes(),
            &token_mint_address.to_bytes(),
        ],
        associated_token_account_program_id,
    )
```

And it's calling `create_account` on the PDA, setting the owner to the token program at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/64d69190dcdfc25fa6041738f843727aa49783ab/associated-token-account/program/src/tools/account.rs#L57

Source at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/64d69190dcdfc25fa6041738f843727aa49783ab/associated-token-account/program/src/lib.rs#L65

So your program can call use `invoke_signed` with a `create_account` instruction, where the owner is *any* program.